# Is there a proof $a^2 = b^n$ where $n>2$ that square of an integer does not equals any cube or above?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I might have a silly questions but I am new to math so don't judge to hard, is there a proof that there is no integer for which $a^n = b^2$ where $n>2$ ?

PS The question excludes the case where (a=c^2$)  (b=c^n$). Example( 4 and 8, 16 should be excluded) also solutions a=b=0 or a=b=1 also to be excluded.

Comment: $9^3=27^2$. In general, $(a^2)^n=(a^n)^2$.

Comment: If $a=c^2$ and $b=c^n$, for any natural number $c$, then in fact $a^n=b^2=c^{2n}$.  For instance, $4^3=8^2$.

Comment: Tnx, but I am talking more about the case where a and b are not equal to c^2 or c^n

Comment: @Hivaga you should edit the question to reflect your intentions if you want to exclude the case that satisfies equation.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow that is a good point :)

Comment: Suggestion for the question you appear to be asking: Consider the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "The question excludes the case where (a=c^2)(b=cn). Example( 4 and 8, 16 should be excluded) also solutions a=b=0 or a=b=1 also to be excluded."  You should *really* clarify your actual question.  The answer to the question is "no" because it isn't true.  If $a = c^k$ and $b=c$ and $n = 2k$ is, of course, a counter example.  You can't say "but that doesn't count because..." because you didn't clarify what you were actually asking form.

Comment: By the dupe if $n$ is odd then $\,a = c^n, b = c^2\,$ for an integer $\,c,\,$ which is excluded. Thus $n$ is even,  where obviously it *is* solvable: let $\,a = b^{n/2}\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers with $a^n = b^2$, where $n> 2$ is an integer.  Then $a = \sqrt[n]{b^2} = [\sqrt[n]{b}]^2$.  You want to know all the ways this can happen.

If $a$ is a perfect square, say $a = c^2$ for a positive integer $c$, then you can take $b = c^n$, and then $a^n = c^{2n} = b^2$.

If $a$ is not a perfect square, then this situation can only happen when $n$ is even.  Indeed, if $a = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_s^{e_s}$ and $b = p_1^{f_1} \cdots p_s^{f_s}$ are the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$ (with $e_i, f_i \geq 0$), then $a^n = b^2$ implies that $ne_i = 2f_i$ for each $i$.  The assumption that $a$ is not a perfect square is equivalent to the claim that some $e_i$ is an odd number.  For such $i$, the equation $ne_i = 2f_i$ implies that $n$ is even, as claimed.

So for $n$ even, *every* positive integer $a$ admits a corresponding positive integer $b$ such that $a^n = b^2$, since you can just take $b = a^{n/2}$ (an integer!).

For example, if $n = 4$, you can take for $(a,b)$ the pairs

$$(1,1); (2^4, 4^2); (3^4,9^2); (4^4,16^2); ...$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known fact that $\sqrt[k]{m}$ (where $m$ is an integer) is an integer only if $m$ is an integer to a $k$ power.

So if $a^2 = b^n$ then either $b$ is a perfect square or $n$ is even.

If $b = c^2$ for some integer $c$ then $a= c^n$ and $a$ is an integer to the $n$th power.

And if $n = 2k$ then $a = b^k$ and $a$ is a perfect $k$ power.  And that's the only way it is possible (although that is quite possible).

I'm not sure what you are looking for but that pretty much exhausts everything.